# Preview screen in android studio not displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am using the latest version of android studio and I can't see the preview screen. Here is an image:

[image]

How can I get the preview to show?

Comment: Correct your sync issue should fix the problem. Else do a clean and rebuild.

Comment: And do set up your SDK, as the error at the bottom of the page indicates.

Comment: It looks like the issue is your android SDK is not configure properly.

Comment: thanks all , but how can i reinstall the SDK . I downloaded it from a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the sdk or find if already downloaded.

Now, in Android Studio set up your sdk location by:

**File menu>Project Structure**

[image]